# Using Odoo External API, is it possible to filter by a field that is equal to array of values?

Tags: java, filter, odoo, xml-rpc

I know how to filter *by value*, but I don't know how to filter by *array of values* (the field contains an array).
I use Odoo 15.0 and XML-RPC to get external access to its database.
In [this doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/api/external_api.html#list-records) I found out how to get records filtered *by a value*:

```java
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl common_config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
String path = "https://my-domain.odoo.com";
common_config.setServerURL(new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/common", path)));
int uid = (int) client.execute(common_config, "authenticate", 
        asList(db_name, login, password, emptyMap()));

final XmlRpcClient models = new XmlRpcClient() {{
    setConfig(new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {{
        setServerURL(new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/object", path)));
    }});
}};

List<Object>listProds = asList((Object[]) models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
    db_name, uid, password,
    "product.pricelist.item", "search_read",
    asList(asList(
        asList("fixed_price", "=", 0.09) // <-- filter setting
    )),
    new HashMap() {{
        put("fields", asList(
            "id", "pricelist_id", "fixed_price", "name"
        ));
        put("limit", 300);
    }}
)));
System.out.println("Read some fields for the products: " + listProds2);
```

For instance, using the code above I get all rows with `fixed_price = 0.09`:

[image]

But I need to filter by `pricelist_id` equals `[2, Catalogue Price (CAD)]`, which is String representation of `Object[]`. The value is an array itself, and here I'm stuck.
I tried different variants of filter syntax but none of them worked.

```
asList("pricelist_id", "=", asList(2, "Catalogue Price (CAD)")) 
// or
asList("pricelist_id", "=", new Object[] {2, "Catalogue Price (CAD)"})
```

give

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "%Catalogue Price (CAD)%"
> LINE 1: ...ND ("product_pricelist_item"."pricelist_id" in (2,'%Catalogu...

And the following variants of syntax have no effect as if the filter is absent:

```
asList("pricelist_id", "=", (new Object[]{2, "Catalogue Price (CAD)"}).toString())

asList("pricelist_id", "like", "%Catalogue Price (CAD)%")

asList("pricelist_id", "=", "2, Catalogue Price (CAD)")

asList("pricelist_id", "=", "[2, Catalogue Price (CAD)]")
```

It would be fine to filter by `pricelist_id` containing "Catalogue Price (CAD)" (one of the array values is enough because they are unique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Odoo will return `(record id, record display_name)` when [reading](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/fields.py#L2808)  a many2one field

To filter the result using a many2one field, you need to use the database id (`2`), example:

```
("pricelist_id", "=", 2)
```

You can also filter by a list of price list ids using the `in` operator:

```
("pricelist_id", "in", list_of_ids )
```

Comment: Great! And so simple